# Passing multiple values from one checkbox to update a table php

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, mysqli

I've got a query which displays the number of unreturned loans (in my library system) as a table, I have a checkbox being displayed as well as for each book so that when the librarian clicks on the ones that HAVE been returned, the field "returned" is set to 1 or true to which ever books the librarian has selected. So far I've only got it echo the value of how many boxes has been selected...This is my code so far:

```
<?php
if ($_SESSION['user_session'] == "nita.patel")
{
 {
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Loan ID</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Book ID</th>
<th>Return Date</th>
<th>Returned?</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['loan_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['book_id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['return_date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value=1 /></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
 }
}
?>

<input type='submit' value='LOANS RETURNED'>



<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
{
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check)
    {
            echo $check;                          
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @HankyPankyㇱ Apologies for being unclear, basically, If i select for example 3 books that have been returned by the borrower by ticking them, how can I update the 'returned' field (which is a boolean) to true for all three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the checkbox line to:

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='check_list[]' value='" . $row['loan_id'] . "' /></td>";
```

This will tell you what ID has been checked.  Currently, everything is being set to 1, and you wont really know which line was checked.

Comment: Thanks, that's half of what I wanted to do, because now that I've got the value of the Loan ID, how would I do an UPDATE query so that the old value for each selection is set to the new value?

Comment: It's okay, I've just got it to work, THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!